# Dealing with cluttering swift optionals

Tags: swift

I am writing some Swift code that should really be simple: initialization of a database class which loads data from a file if available or returns an empty database otherwise.

The issue is, my code seems overly complicated and I think there might be a better way of dealing with optional values that I fail to see.

Here is how I do it vs. how I would like it to be :

**How I do**

```
class Database: NSObject
{
    private var database:    [String: [AnyObject]]
    private var databasePath: String

    init(databasePath: String)
    {
        self.databasePath = databasePath

        if let db1 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(databasePath)
        {
            if let db2 = db1 as? [String : [AnyObject]]
            {
                database = db2
            }
            else
            {
                database = [String: [AnyObject]]()
            }
        }
        else
        {
            database = [String: [AnyObject]]()
        }

        super.init()
    }
}
```

**How I would like it to be**

```
class Database: NSObject
{
    private var database:    [String: [AnyObject]]
    private var databasePath: String

    init(databasePath: String)
    {
        self.databasePath = databasePath

        if !(let database = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(databasePath) as? [String : [AnyObject]])
        {
            database = [String: [AnyObject]]()
        }

        super.init()
    }
}
```

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify it to

```
if let db = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(databasePath) as? [String : [AnyObject]] {
    database =  db
} else {
    database = [:]
}
```

or even to a single statement, using the "nil-coalescing operator" `??`:

```
database = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(databasePath) as? [String : [AnyObject]] ?? [:]
```

This evaluates to the first expression

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(databasePath) as? [String : [AnyObject]]
```

if that is not `nil`, and to the empty dictionary `[:]` otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Is there a way to affect it directly to `database` instead of using a temporary `let db` ? As I understand it, dictionaries are structures in swift and are passed by copy. For a large database, it would be much better to avoid any unnecessary copies.

Comment: @John: 1) the second proposed solution *does* assign to `database` directly. – 2) You are right that dictionaries are value types, but internally they do a "copy on write", so simply assigning `db` to `database` is cheap.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I read the documentation on the nil-coalescing operator and adopted that technique. Thanks.